# Get current active class of an ul

Tags: jquery, css, class, html-lists

Say you have the following.

```
  .pic {
      display: none;
    }

    .pic.show {
      display: block;
    }

    <ul>
       <li class='pic show'><img src="1.jpg"></li>
       <li class='pic'><img src="2.jpg"></li>
       <li class='pic'><img src="3.jpg"></li>
       <li class='pic'><img src="4.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to write a simple dynamic bit of jQuery that would find the li that has the class = 'pic show'.

So my question is, how would you go about finding the li that has the current class of `class = 'pic show'` applied to it?

Comment: You realise that while we can answer your explicit question ("how do I select the relevant element?"), we could offer *better* answers if you told us what, precisely, you were trying to *do* with that element, or on what event you wished to *find* that element. Incidentally, what did you try, and where were you stuck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("ul li.show")` to find the li element with a class of show which is a child of the ul.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same selector as in your CSS:

```
$('.pic.show')
```

If you want to specify that it must be an `li` element:

```
$('li.pic.show')
```